# I need help in optimizing this stored proc. If possible without cursor

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, group-by, cursor

```
Declare @CurrentDate   varchar(25)
Declare @PreviousDate  varchar(25)
Declare @MaxDate       varchar(25)

Declare Cursor1 Cursor  For
Select Distinct ProductID
    From   Products
    Where  ProductId Is Not Null
    Order By ProductId

Declare @ProductID varchar(14)

Open Cursor1
Fetch Next From Cursor1 Into @ProductId
While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
    Select @MaxDate = Max(ProductDate)
    From   Products
    Where  ProductId = @ProductID

    Declare Cursor2 Cursor For 
    Select ProductDate 
    From   Products
    Where  ProductId = @ProductID    
    Order  By ProductDate

    Open Cursor2
    Fetch Next From Cursor2 Into @CurrentDate
    Begin Try
        While (@@Fetch_Status = 0) 
        Begin
            If @PreviousDate Is Not Null And 
               @CurrentDate Is Not Null And 
               @PreviousDate != @MaxDate
            Begin
                Update Products 
                Set ProductEndDate = @CurrentDate 
                Where ProductId = @ProductId 
                And ProductDate = @PreviousDate  
            End                 
            Set @PreviousDate  = @CurrentDate

            Fetch Next From Cursor2 Into @CurrentDate   
        End
        Close Cursor2
        Deallocate Cursor2
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Declare @error INT,@message varchar(4000);
        Select 
            @error = error_number(), 
            @message = error_message();
        Close Cursor2
        Deallocate Cursor2
    End Catch
End 
Close Cursor1
Deallocate Cursor1
```

Comment: You don't appear to keep fetching from cursor1, so this will probably never end.

Comment: Some table definitions, example data and expected results would help here. Are you really using `varchar(25)` columns to store dates, for example?

Comment: Yes we are using varchar(25) for dates here. I know it seems odd but that's the way old data is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite the same, if you have duplicate `ProductID, ProductDate` combinations, but it may get you on track:

Simplified by Martin Smith

```
;With cte as (
    Select
        ProductID,
        ProductEndDate,
        ProductDate,
        row_number() over (partition by ProductID order By ProductDate) rn
    From
        Products
)
Update
    x
Set
    x.ProductEndDate = y.ProductDate
From
    cte x
        inner join
    cte y
        on x.ProductID = y.ProductID and
           x.rn = y.rn - 1;
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/847d8/3)</kbd>**

An index on `ProductId, ProductDate` will make this faster.

Comment: [Why two CTEs?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/847d8/3)

Comment: @MartinSmith There are some circumstances where you can't refer to the same CTE twice, and I never remember the rules (now I think about it I think that's for recursive CTEs). I'll update it with your suggestion, as it's clearly better, thanks.